# Prove that H is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $G = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : a,b\in (\mathbb{R}) , a \neq 0\right\}$

and assume G is a group under matrix multpication

Prove that H = $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a normal subgroup of G

I know I am meant to show that the left coset is equal to the right coset, but how do i approach this?

Comment: The notation is a little bit deficient.  I think you mean for $G$ to denote a *set* of such matrices, not a particular (real) $2\times 2$ matrix.  I bet you posted the curly brackets without escaping them (let me try and fix it for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\forall h\in H,\space\forall g\in G,\, ghg^{-1}\in H$

So let's take $g=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in G$.

One has $g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a^{-1}&-a^{-1}b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

And so

$$ghg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a^{-1}&-a^{-1}b+t\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

And we get

$$ghg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&*\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in H$$

QED

Comment: Ahh cheers, I actually just figured it out be showing the left coset and the right coset are equal, but thanks for your help

Comment: I find that the "left cosets and right cosets are equal" definition harder to work with in some cases. Often it is much more straightforward to use the equivalent definition that is used in this answer: $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if for all $h \in H$ and $g \in G$ we have $g h g^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

I will show $H$ to be normal by proving that it is the kernel of a homomorphism.

Define $f\colon G \to \mathbb R^*$ (the group of non-zero reals under multiplication), as $f\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = a$. Since $\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2 & a_1b_2 + b_1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $f$ is clearly a homomorphism (for it maps the product to $a_1a_2$). The kernel of $f$ is the set of all matrices in $G$ that are mapped to $1$, the identity element of $\mathbb R^*$ — i.e., the set of all matrices of the given form with $a = 1$. This proves the result.